# How do I increase the algorithm performance for longer array of numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sortedlist

Thanks for looking.

Count how many numbers are less than 4 in an ordered array of numbers.

**How do I increase the algorithm performance for longer array of numbers?** Increase the calculation speed. Does binary search help? Outputs?

```
    public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0, len = sortedArray.Length; i < len; i++)
            if (sortedArray[i] < lessThan)
                count++;
            else return count;

        return count;
    }

Assert.AreEqual(SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4), 2);
```

Comment: Use BinarySearch

Comment: What happened when  you tried using a binary search?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Binary search of what number ?

Comment: @Tigran of `lessThan` number

Comment: @Adam83: use divide and conquer approach to bring it as close as possible  to O(logn) rather than O(n) as you have it now.

Comment: @Tigran O(n log(n)) is *more* than O(n), not less.  A binary search is O(log(n)).

Comment: @Servy: typo, corrected, thanks: was thinking of quick-sort while writing.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: thing is that we do not *search* for `lessThan`, but rather for set of numbers less than it, but I think everyone got what you mean, me included.

Comment: Not sure if binary will effect the outcome. The algorithm should only count how many numbers before the giving number. The list has already been sorted low to high.

Comment: As stated, binary search is your friend. Use implementation that returns position of searched value in the given array (if we insert this value).

Comment: So I keep chopping the list down until I find the number. I then count =  index + 1? Would that take more execution when chopping the list down and then getting numbers from the array to compare them? Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Array.BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
{
    if (sortedArray[0] >= lessThan) return 0;

    int lengthOfArray = sortedArray.Length;
    if (lengthOfArray == 0) return 0;
    if (sortedArray[lengthOfArray - 1] < lessThan) return lengthOfArray;

    int index = Array.BinarySearch(sortedArray, lessThan);
    if (index < 0)
        return ~index;
    // Find first occurrence in case of duplicate
    for (; index > 0 && sortedArray[index - 1] == lessThan; index--) ;
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A good approach for a problem like this is to split your array in smaller parts and with the help of a `ThreadPool` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx) increase the calculation speed.

Comment: Binary search isn't really possible to make multithreaded because each operation performed depends on the results of the previous operation. You could do *n*-ary search where *n* is the number of threads plus one, but single-threaded binary search is so fast, and *n*-ary search would require so much inter-thread communication, that I can't imagine threads being useful here at all.