# How to optimize a loops going through arrays?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I've been going though www.testdome.com to test my skills and opened a list of public questions. One of the practice questions was:

> Implement function CountNumbers that accepts a sorted array of
>   integers and counts the number of array elements that are less than
>   the parameter lessThan.
>
> For example, SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4)
>   should return 2 because there are two array elements less than 4.

And my answer was:

```
using System;

public class SortedSearch
{
    public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int l = sortedArray.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (sortedArray [i] < lessThan)
                count++;
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SortedSearch.CountNumbers(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }, 4));
    }
}
```

It seems that I've failed on two counts:

`Performance test when sortedArray contains lessThan: Time limit exceeded`
and
`Performance test when sortedArray doesn't contain lessThan: Time limit exceeded`

To be honest I'm not sure what to optimize there? Maybe I'm using a wrong method and there is a similar way to speed up the calculation?

If someone could point out my mistake or explain what I'm going wrong, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Do you only want to optimize counting through the array like this, or also consider other algorithms?

Comment: Any algorithm is fine, I think

Comment: You can binary search for the boundary between "less than" and "not less than", it's a little trickier than the plain binary search that you usually find..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the algorithm performance for longer array of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805768/how-do-i-increase-the-algorithm-performance-for-longer-array-of-numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the array is sorted, you can stop counting as soon as you reach or exceed the `lessThan` parameter.

`else break` would probably do it.

Comment: Oh, that went right over my head! I was looking at the word `sorted` and it didn't click until you've pointed it out. Need to be more careful with the wording.

Comment: Changed my loop to:  

`for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
   if (sortedArray [i] >= lessThan)
                return count;
   count++;
  }`

but still get the same errors.

Comment: You could binary sort and end on `lessThan', returning the index

Comment: @LoztInSpace You mean Binary search?

Comment: Doh! Yes @IpsitGaur  but upvote Harold if you haven't already - his answer is the correct one that answers the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be really a loop? You could do Lambda exp for that

```
public static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
{
    return sortedArray.ToList().Where(x=>x < lessThan).Count();
}
```

Comment: That is true and is arguably a better style but it won't be a optimal because `Where()` will not know that it can terminate before reaching the end of the collection (because it's sorted).

Comment: Right... I get your point. Looping through a large array can prematurely stop the loop if the condition is met while a Where() will have to go through all of the elements.

Comment: Correct.  But as Harold says, a binary search would often be a better solution anyway. Interesting how easy it is to not think outside the frame put in front of us (looping in this case). We both got caught by that!

Comment: Also `Where` is internally a loop (for collections anyway, not if e.g. against a database) so it's the same thing. If anything we'd turn `Where` into a loop to optimise if it was in a hot spot (not worth doing all the time, as it's best to keep to the clarity and concision of `Where` but the question is about optimising). You should also remove the `ToList()` which is just a waste of time and memory with no benefit here.

Comment: [`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.110).aspx) could be used instead of `Where`.

Answer (score 0):

**Harold's answer and approach is spot on.**

Find below another code sample in case you're practicing for technical interviews. It handles cases when the array is null or empty, when **lessThan** is presented in the array (including duplicates), etc.

```
    private static int CountNumbers(int[] sortedArray, int lessThan)
    {
        if (sortedArray == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Sorted array cannot be null.");
        }

        if (sortedArray.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Sorted array cannot be empty.");
        }

        int start = 0;
        int end = sortedArray.Length;
        int middle = int.MinValue;

        while (start < end)
        {
            middle = (start + end) / 2;

            if (sortedArray[middle] == lessThan)
            {
                break; // Found the "lessThan" number in the array, we can stop and move left
            }
            else if (sortedArray[middle] < lessThan)
            {
                start = middle + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                end = middle - 1;
            }
        }

        // Adjust the middle pointer based on the "current" and "lessThan" numbers in the sorted array
        while (middle >= 0 && sortedArray[middle] >= lessThan) 
        {
            middle--;
        }

        // +1 because middle is calculated through 0-based (e.g. start)
        return middle + 1; 
    }
```

Comment: I disagree that an empty array is an error. It's the same case with the same answer (0) as with a non-empty array.

Comment: Actually your answer returns 3 errors - it seems it doesn't work with different test-cases. Funny enough - one thing that did improve was the speed of calculation :)

Comment: Great :)! I found/fixed one. Send me an edit with the other 2 and I'll accept it. ;)